# How to send file with fastify & nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, fastify

I have the following front end middleware:

```
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
        const url = req.originalUrl;
        if (url.indexOf('rest') === 1) {
            next();
        } else if (allowedExt.filter(ext => url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
            res.sendFile(resolvePath(url));
        } else {
            res.sendFile(resolvePath('index.html'));
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine with express, but with fastify, `res.sendFile` is `undefined`, so how can I fix that?

Comment: Oh, didn't work for you after all or why did you unaccept?

Comment: reply.type is undefined either

Comment: Did you use `res.type`?

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/163#issuecomment-323070670). `sendFile` has no equivalent method in fastify; you have to do it manually:

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(resolvePath('index.html'))
res.type('text/html').send(stream)
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering why your response is empty.
Try adding a `return` before `res.type('text/html').send(stream)`

Comment: @e.marten insteresting, you are right. But why we need to do this?

Comment: @user3032481 Honestly, I can't say for sure. It might be because it's a read stream and my route was needlessly using an async function. If I remove async I could also remove the return statement
I did however end up with a different solution.
Instead of creating a read stream and returning that, I used `readFile` from `fs/promises`. I made sure to read the file once, outside my route declaration, that way I could minimize disk access by only reading the file once when my server starts up instead of once per request.
When using `readFile` you don't need to add a return statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can also store index.html in memory and send it from it:

```
const bufferIndexHtml = fs.readFileSync('index.html')
res.type('text/html').send(bufferIndexHtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to use the fastify-static module provided by Fastify. They have some good examples for sending a file. More information can be found about it here - https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static

Here's an example of sending a file -

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger: true})
const path = require('path')

fastify.register(require('@fastify/static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  prefix: '/public/', // optional: default '/'
})

fastify.get('/sendHtmlFile', function (req, reply) {
  reply.sendFile('myHtml.html') // serving path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'myHtml.html') directly
})

// Run the server!
fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err, address) => {
  if (err) throw err
  // Server is now listening on ${address}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript, declare it like:

```js
import fastifyStatic from "@fastify/static";
export const server = fastify({
  logger: true,
});

server.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "/.testdata/uploads"),
  //prefix: "/public/", // optional: default '/'
  //constraints: { host: "example.com" }, // optional: default {}
});
```

Functions/types like `sendFile` will be found.