# How I can use sendFile in fastify?

Tags: fastify

**Server.ts**

```
import fastify from "fastify";
import cookie from 'fastify-cookie';
import apiRoute from './routes/api';
import jwtPlugin from "./plugins/jwtPlugin";
import closePlugin from "./plugins/closePlugin";
import path from "path";

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT!, 10)

export default class Server {
    app = fastify({ logger: true })

    constructor() {
        this.setup()
    }

    setup() {
        this.app.get('/', (request, reply) => {
            reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
        })
        this.app.register(apiRoute, { prefix: '/api' })
        this.app.register(cookie)
        this.app.register(require('fastify-url-data'))
        this.app.register(jwtPlugin)
        this.app.register(closePlugin)
        this.app.setErrorHandler((error, request, reply) => {
            reply.send({
                statusCode: error.statusCode,
                name: error.name,
                message: error.message,
                validation: error.validation,
                stack: error.stack,
            })
        })
        this.app.register(require('fastify-rate-limit'), {
            max: 100,
            timeWindow: '1 minute'
        })
        this.app.register(require('fastify-static'), {
            root: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
        })
    }
```

**version/index.ts**

```
const versionRoute: FastifyPluginCallback = (fastify, opts, done) => {

    //Todo 1. get version of app
    //Define request body to fastify
    fastify.post(
        //Route
        '/version_info',
        async (request, reply) => {

            try {
                const result: VersionBody[] = await Version.getVersionInfo("testServer")
                reply.send(result[0])
            } catch (error) {
                reply.status(500)
                reply.send({
                    code: 500,
                    error: "Version Error",
                    message: error
                })
            }
        }
    )

    //Todo 2. get update file
    //Define request body to fastify
    fastify.get('/update_file', function (req, reply) {
        reply.sendFile(...)
    })    
    
    done()
}

export default versionRoute
```

Hi, I have a question.
I want to send the file, when request to specific url.
So, I install fastify-specific and register.

But, it show error message like,
'FastifyReply<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, RouteGenericInterface, unknown>' type does not have property 'sendFile'

How I can register reply.sendFile in fastify?

or Is there any way to send file in fastify?

If you know about it, please help me.

Comment: See this for alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55884701/7421086 ; Though would be nice if someone could figure out how to get `sendFile` working...